# Laravel: get last insert id and show it before registration

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I need to display the last value of id,in an input form when I open the page of regestration ( befor to add a new user). help me

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="{{$last_id}}" >
```

but I don't have any idea about where I have to set this ligne:

```
$last_id =DB::table('clients')->max('id');
```

Comment: Order by latest `->` first `->` id

Comment: I recommend you to get an introduction on Laravel and the MVC pattern in general. I don't think incrementing a database id should be done on a form placed on the view.

Comment: there is any way  to do it with javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of this is to have the right incremented value when you create the client, the database can handle it for you if you wrote your migration the right way. If it's the case, just paste your migration for the `clients` table and I'll show you the way to do it.

If you just want to display it, you can write it that way, but make sure this is the right way to do what you want to do here :

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="{{ DB::table('clients')->max('id') }}" >
```

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: thaaaaaaaank u  a lot sir it worked just u need to delete the ( ; )  u can correct it